TypeORM One-To-One Relationship Showing as Many-To-One/One-To-Many in PostgreSQL ERD
I'm using TypeORM with NestJS to establish a one-to-one relationship between two tables, but when I view the ERD in pgAdmin, it's showing up as a many-to-one/one-to-many relationship instead. I have included my code snippets and an image of the ERD for reference.
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
@ObjectType()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @Field((type) => Int)
    id: number

    @Column()
    @Field()
    username: string

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    @Field({ nullable: true })
    displayName?: string

    @OneToOne(() => UserSetting)
    @JoinColumn()
    @Field({ nullable: true })
    settings?: UserSetting
}

@Entity({ name: 'user_settings' })
@ObjectType()
export class UserSetting {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    @Field((type) => Int)
    userId: number

    @Column({ default: false })
    @Field({ defaultValue: false })
    receiveNotifications: boolean

    @Column({ default: false })
    @Field({ defaultValue: false })
    receiveEmails: boolean
}


In pgAdmin, you can check relationship, this should appear as one-to-one. Has anyone else encountered this? Could there be something I'm missing in the configuration?

After some research, this issue is not because of typeorm and its relationship. It is because of pgAdmin. You can check the answer that I have added.

The issue we encountered appear due to the pgAdmin bug as per the below references.

1 to 1 relation postgres
https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/5128

The relationship we defined in code first approach is correct it is showing wrong relationship due to pgAdmin bugs. I have used DbBeaver to generate ER diagram and it shows correct relationship over there.

Why PostgreSQL Shows it as Many-to-One/One-to-Many:
I Think it's because UserSetting didn't have userId set as a primary key, PostgreSQL treated it as a One-to-Many relationship, where multiple settings could be linked to a single user.
By making userId the primary key in UserSetting, you ensure that each user can only have one setting, thus enforcing the one-to-one relationship.
Here’s how you can modify your entities:
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
@ObjectType()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @Field((type) => Int)
    id: number;

    @Column()
    @Field()
    username: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    @Field({ nullable: true })
    displayName?: string;

    @OneToOne(() => UserSetting, (setting) => setting.user, { cascade: true })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'userSettingId' })
    @Field({ nullable: true })
    settings?: UserSetting;
}

@Entity({ name: 'user_settings' })
@ObjectType()
export class UserSetting {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    @Field((type) => Int)
    userId: number;

    @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.settings)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })
    user: User;

    @Column({ default: false })
    @Field({ defaultValue: false })
    receiveNotifications: boolean;

    @Column({ default: false })
    @Field({ defaultValue: false })
    receiveEmails: boolean;
}


Thank you for sharing this answer as this is useful for bidirectional relationships. I have added answer as it may help somebody in future.
